# How to parallelize in windows without requiring firewall permissions

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I know that R since version 2.14.0 comes with the `parallel` package, 
so you can do for example this:

```
library(parallel)

cl <- makeCluster(2) # parallelize by 2

res <- clusterApply(cl,1:20,
                    function(x)
{
   # long stupid elaboration...
   currmean <- 0
   count <- 0
   for(a in 1:100){
     for(b in 1:100){
       for(c in 1:100){
           currmean <- currmean + 1/(count+1) * (x - currmean)
           count <- count + 1
       }
     }
   }
   return(currmean)
}
)
```

The problem is that the following approach (at least on windows) requires firewall permissions since it opens a socket for each cluster, but this is sometimes not possible or difficult (e.g. in some production environments).

Is there an alternative package/way that does not require firewall permissions, for example something relying on threads ?

Comment: The doSMP package with foreach used shared memory rather than networking, but it is now defunct.  I'm not aware of any parallel programming package that works on Windows that will avoid the use of sockets for communication.